# How to close correctly a Qt program?

Tags: c++, qt

When I try to close my Qt program, it just keeps running in the background though there's no window anymore.

Basically, I would like to know what I should do so it closes properly when I click the red cross on my main window (which has no parent).

[Following this link](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/6691), I tried a few things like :

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
//...
app.connect(&app, SIGNAL(lastWindowClosed()), &app, SLOT(quit()));
return app.exec();
```

or

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
//...
app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(true);
return app.exec();
```

but neither work, the process still stays in memory, after the cross is clicked.

Then, how can I close correctly my program ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can close your application manually using `QApplication::quit()`.

By default the execution is terminated when the last top level window with the `Qt::WA_QuitOnClose` attribute has been closed. You don't need to connect `lastWindowClosed` to `quit` because it repeats the default `setQuitOnLastWindowClosed` behavior. You don't need to do `setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(true)` either because it's true by default. The code you've posted does nothing (if nothing is changed somewhere else).

Possible solutions:

- Check your main window attributes. Maybe you have removed `Qt::WA_QuitOnClose` attribute.
- If you have reimplemented `closeEvent` in your top level window, check that close event is being accepted.
- Check if there are some other top level widgets that may be hidden but not closed. Use `QApplication::topLevelWidgets()` to list them.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. I did nothing with the `Qt::WA_QuitOnClose` attribute, though, but i'll try to reimplement `closeEvent()`, I didn't read anything about it while searching.

Comment: No, if you don't need to reimplement closeEvent, you should not do that. It must work fine by default. I meant that if you reimplemented closeEvent, your implementation may be incorrect.

Comment: Oh, indeed. Well, I haven't reimplemented it at all... So, what should I do then ? I must absolutely rely on `QApplication::quit()` ?

Comment: Check `QApplication::topLevelWidgets()`.

Comment: Just saw there is actually 8 widgets in the list it returns. So that means that when my window exits, there's still 7 widget that are still present "at top level" and keep the program running (if I understand correctly) ? I really don't know which these are.

Comment: Try to use `qDebug() <<` to get some information about them (class names at least). Also try to iterate through list and call `show()` for each widget. It will help you to find out what are these widgets.

Comment: I iterated through the list, and observed that there is my main window (which I find logic), but also two `QDialog`s for which I specified my main window as parent (then, why are they in the topLevelWidgetList ?), plus a bunch of `QMenu`s (and I don't understand that either)

Comment: Take a look at `QDialog::QDialog()` documentation: 'A dialog is always a top-level widget, but if it has a parent, its default location is centered on top of the parent.' I don't think QMenu will cause the problem. It might be that `Qt::WA_QuitOnClose` flag is disabled for them.